# Sass ancestor class

Tags: css, sass

I have a class .red

I want to apply more rules to labels with the class red.

I know I can do this:

```
label {
   ...stuff...
   &.red {
     color: red;
   }
}
```

but for organization I'd rather something like:

```
.red {
   color: red;
   label & {
    font-weight: normal;
   }
 }
```

But this of course gives me `label .red` not `label.red`

Is there a way to do this, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Not allowed.  You have to write it like your first example or not nest it at all.